# what does this weird dot means in Firefox?

Tags: html, wordpress, firefox

I have customize the them of some widgets in WordPress but instead of customised widgets ,this

[image]

black dot comes .I have checked the source code but there is no code related to this dot.But in Chrome every thing appear as it is  expected.

Comment: Without seeing the code ,its hard to suggest ?

Comment: Looks like a ol, ul or li element that has a dot as list-style.

Comment: perhaps it is the un-ordered list's bullet point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used UL for tag text? then use use css `list-style: none` to UL, otherwise update your post with code